# Number of ways to place $25$ passengers in the bus with $49$ seats with a restriction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> A bus has $49$ seats divided into $22$ pairs of $2$ neighbouring seats(numbers $1-44,$ the neighbouring seats are $(1,2),(3,4),\ldots,(43,44),$ while $(2,3)$ are separated seats) and $5$ seats in the end of the bus.
>
> The passengers are sitting according to a greedy algorithm: if there is nobody sitting on the seats numbered $45-49,$ a passenger sits on one of those. Otherwise, they sit on one of the first $44$ seats with an empty neighbouring seat. If there are none of free pairs of seats, an there is only one person sitting in the end of the bus, they sit on the remaining seats in the end. If there are no free pairs of seats and there are at least $2$ people in the end of the bus,a passenger finds any free seat.
>
> In how many different ways can we place passengers in the bus? Note: it is not important if a person $A$ sat on the seat number $1$ before a person $B$ sat on the seat number $3$ and vice-versa.

**My attempt:**

We can choose $1$ out of $25$ passengers to be the first one and sit in one of the seats $45-49$. There are $\color{red}{25\cdot 5=125}$ ways of doing that. Next, there are $24$ people left, $22$ of whom can sit in either of the seats in the $22$ pairs of seats. We can do that in $\color{red}{2\cdot (24\cdot23\cdots 3)=2\binom{24}{22}\cdot 22=44\binom{24}{22}}$ ways. Then, the $24^{\mathrm{th}}$ person is chosen among the two left and will sit on one of the $4$ seats in the end, there are $\color{red}{2\cdot 4=8}$ ways of doing that. Finally the $25^{\mathrm{th}}$ person can choose any of the remaining $\color{red}{25}$ seats. Therefore, my answer to in how many ways we can place $25$ passengers in the bus is $125\cdot 44\binom{24}{22}\cdot 8\cdot 25.$

Can somebody verify my answer?

Comment: Not sure  I see the problem.  With $25$ people, we know the five special seats are taken, leaving $20$ people...and those $20$ people have no need to share a double seat (as there are $20$ double seats).  I'm not sure which arrangements you are calling equivalent, but whatever the rules for that are the count should not be bad.

Comment: You said the order of seating does not matter but the way you count, seems you care about who gets to sit first

Comment: @lulu after the first person sit, the next 22 will sit in one of the 22 double chairs such that no one sit next to each other

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja  Ah,  I see.  So, that accounts for $23$ people...and then the last two sit in the special seats?  Odd rules.  And I still don't know which arrangements are equivalent.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja, I've checked again the exact numbers, and, it says it isn't important if a person $A$ sat on the set number $1$ and person $B$ on the seat $3$. My conclusion is that they meant those seats not to be the ones in pairs.

Comment: The way you count, person A sit first on seat number $45$ and person $B$ sit second to last on seat number $47$ is different from person B sit first on seat number $47$ and then person A sit second to last on seat number $45$

Comment: @lulu the $24$th person sit in one of the $5$ chairs at the end but the last person can sit in any empty seat. I agree with you, quite bizarre rule

Comment: Thank you! Now I see I misunderstood the task. Let me just read your answer carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first $23$ seats filled will be one front seat and $22$ from double seats. Now the following clause.

"If there are none of free pairs of seats, and there is only one person sitting in the end of the bus, they sit on the remaining seats in the end. If there are no free pairs of seats and there are at least 2 people in the end of the bus, a passenger finds any free seat."

I interpret it to mean

- The $24$th passenger must occupy a front seat
- The $25$th passenger can now occupy any seat

Thus, before permuting the persons, seats can be occupied in

$\binom51*2^{22}*\binom41*\binom{25}1$

and total arrangements $= \boxed{5*2^{22}*4*25*25!}$

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be divided into two sub problem:

1. Which seats are occupied
2. Which person sit on which seat

**Which seats are occupied**

There are two possibilities:

- $3$ out of $5$ seats at the back are occupied and $1$ of each pair from the $22$ pairs in front are occupied
- $2$ out of $5$ seats at the back are occupied and $1$ of each pair from the $22$ pairs in front are occupied but $1$ of the pairs is fully occupied

The number of possibilities are $\binom{5}{3}\times 2^{22}+\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{22}{1}\times 2^{21}$

**Which person sit on which seat**

This is a simple permutation of the selected seats. Possibilities are $25!$

**Combine the two problem**

Total way of seating the persons are

$$
25!\left(\binom{5}{3}\times 2^{22}+\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{22}{1}\times 2^{21}\right)
$$

Comment: As you have commented elsewhere, "@lulu the 24th person sit in one of the 5 chairs at the end but the last person can sit in any empty seat." With these rules three people in the front seats isn't possible.

Comment: Not sure if I get that, since the last person is free to choose any empty seat he can also choose one of the five seat at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I garbled what I meant. The order of seating is **very specific** (# of ways in brackets) First goes to front $(5)$, next $22$ occupy the back $(2^{22})$, the $24$th **has** to go front where there are $4$ vacant seats, so the two together occupy the front seats in $(5*4)$ ways, not $\binom52$ ways. Finally, the last man has all $25$ choices. The way you have computed for the front seats, it appears as if they were allowed to sit in $\binom52\;or\binom53$ ways earlier, which is surely incorrect ?

Comment: @trueblueanil say person $A$ sit in seat $45$ and person $B$ in seat $46$, from what I understand whether person $A$ is the first to sit and person $B$ the $24$th or the other way around is considered the same in this question. The way you count, these are counted as different

Comment: Were that so, then the wording would simply have been something like *two or three people sit in the front seats, and the rest sit singly in the back double seats as far as possible* instead of the long harangue about the greedy algorithm.

Comment: @trueblueanil maybe yes, or maybe the question is meant to confuse people especially the last note